# What is the best image fromat and size for products in magento

Tags: magento-1, configurable-product, import, csv

I am new on Magento and as per my requirements, I have to import the products data along with images using CSV files and my all of products images are placed in a remote location, let say `http://www.xxxxxxx.com/magentoimages/`.

I have below question here.

1. Which image format(JPEG,PNG,GIF etc.) should use for better performance in remote location.
2. What should be the max image file size for each and every image for better performance.
3. What should be the max height and width of image for better performance.

I have gone through the below link and he suggest the below ideal Size & resolution for magento product images.

File Format: JPEG
Max. Width: 1600 pixels
Max. Height: 1200 pixels
Max. File Size: 200 kb

I am not sure on this so please help me or guide me as I have to provide the above information to my Client as soon as possible.

Comment: Practically speaking, it all depends on your theme and the UI design of your pages......but it is advisable to keep low file size image and resolution keeping performance of your website...

Comment: Hi Siddharth,
Thanks for your response.Further I need the details for product images only. If I talk about the UI then I have to show 10*6 matrix in the homepage, I mean around 60 product images in one page but for this view we will display the product images in 50*50 pixel.

Comment: What is this "remote location"? Maybe you should look into an image CDN (e.g. Amazon S3: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aws-s3-cdn-for-product-images.html). There are also many design factors to consider such as Retina displays or other high-definition screens.

Answer (score 9):

**File formats**
Personally I find JPGs to be perfectly fine for use across Magento unless you need transparency, then 24bit PNG would be the way to go. Keep in mind PHP will compress the file when it dynamically renders the image, so you should supply the highest quality JPG you can (set quality to maximum when exporting from Photoshop or similar).

If you are exporting from Photoshop, make sure you choose "Save as for web", as this will produce much smaller file sizes for the same quality image as it strips out EXIF data and optimises the image for web. See [here](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/save-as-save-for-web.html) for more information.

**File size**
File sizes will completely depend on the dimensions of your images. There's no maximum allowed filesize but your server will need to process the image to generate resized version so don't use huge files. What you have mentioned in your question is fine.

**Dimensions**
Magento (see `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`) will automatically resize your images to the correct dimensions as specified in your template files. You should upload images with dimensions greater than or equal to the largest instance of it on your site. For example, if you have a main product image that can be displayed in a zoom panel that requires it to be 1500x1500 then you will need to supply an image at least 1500x1500. If the same image is used for the category page at 200x200 then PHP will resize it appropriately.

You can control the quality of the rendered image by adjusting your PHTML files:

`$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->setQuality(90);`

There are also additional PHP libraries other than the default gd2 that you can use that would provide higher quality rendering of images.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) seems to be a popular one for better down scaling and avoiding artefacts like [moiring](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moir%C3%A9-how-can-we-avoid-it)

Answer (score -3):

Hi For better performance you can use PNG image format for your Magento store. And different image has different size it's depend on image pixels. for example you use banner and your banner is `1500 X 1000 pixels` and you are use image in products and products image is `200 X 100 pixels`. My suggestion is use images in PNG format.

Comment: Hi Wajid,
Thanks for your response.Further, I would like to share with you that as per my requirement, I will get only a single image for a product and I have to use the same image for different views(thumnail,small and base) of the product in the website that is why I am asking what should be the max height and width of the image so that it will looks proper(good quality) in all sections.

Comment: Client asking me the max height and width along with the max file size and format of the image so that he can place the same file on a remote location and then I have to download the image and resized the same image for all 3 views (without losing the image quality)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend PNG in most cases, depends on the pictures. With photographs, always use JPG.